# How do I make a video swap for a different video when I hover over a thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm making a video and image gallery for a project I'm working on.  I want to be able to have a larger img/video and then a series of thumbnails that when you hover over them changes swaps to the larger img/video. Trying to replicate something like this https://angel.co/payward-kraken.

I've been able to do the swap with images but haven't been able to find out how to do it with video. Any ideas on how I could do this? I'm a bit new with jquery so I don't understand fully yet.

This is what I have so far:

Javascript

```
$('#imgDetail li img').hover(function(){
        $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="divVideo"> 
   <video width="543" height="362"controls> <source src="assets/img/Traackr.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
   </video>
</div>
<div id="imgDetail">
                <img src="assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" alt="" id="bigImg" class="img-responsive"/>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing2.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing3.png" class="thumb" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing4.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing5.png" class="thumb" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing6.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got an inidivual video playing yet? If so how are you placing that on your page? Look at using an additional library like FlowPlayer (http://flowplayer.org/). I've use flowplyer a fair bit and it has a fairly comprehensive API to use.

Comment: I've been able to get the individual video playing with the formatting I have right now but when I hover over the rest of the images nothing changes. When I do just images everything works fine. Any ideas? I'm looking into the Flowplayer as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you add the code where you have video playing?

Comment: Sure. This is what I've edited it to. I replaced the first <img src> line for: 

<div id="divVideo">
<video width="543" height="362"controls>        <source src="assets/img/Traackr.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

And then the img list is the same as above. 

I also removed the div id="imgDetail and changed it for the div id= divVideo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd update your HTML to wrap the images in links to the video urls. Something like...

```
<div id="imgDetail">
    <img src="assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" alt="" id="bigImg" class="img-responsive"/>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="/url/to/video1.mp4><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="/url/to/video2.mp4><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing2.png"  class="thumb" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="/url/to/video3.mp4><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing3.png" class="thumb" /></a>
       </li>
       <!--- Etc--->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Update you javascript to the following...

```
var myVideo = $("#divVideo video");

$('#imgDetail li a').hover(function(){
        var vidURL = $(this).attr('href');
        myVideo.src = vidURL;
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
}).click(function(){
    //Disable nav if link clicked
    return false;
});
```

I've not tested this but grabbed a lot of the detail from an [Apple Turorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html)

**Update**

So we want to replace an image with a video, not change a video source. This is very different. You will want to have an image element **and** a video element. Also you will need to identify which item is the video thumnail. I've used a `video` class to do this. I've made the final list item the video thumbnail in the following example.

HTML

```
<div id="imgDetail">
<video  width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/Traackr.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
    <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/traackr2.png" id="bigImg" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing2.png"  class="thumb" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing3.png" class="thumb" />
       </li>
       <!-- Note the addition of the video class on the image -->
        <li ><img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing4.png" class="thumb video" /></li>
       <!--- Etc--->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add the following CSS to have the video hidden on page load

```
#imgDetail video
{
    display:none;
}
```

Now update your javascript with the following:

```
$('#imgDetail li img').not(".video").hover(function(){
        $('#imgDetail video').hide(); //Hide the video if it's showing;
        $('#bigImg').show(); //Show the image if it's hidden       
        $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src')); //Update the image source
});

$('#imgDetail li img.video').hover(function(){
        $('#bigImg').hide();//Hide the image if its showing
        $('#imgDetail video').show(); //Show The video
        //$('#imgDetail video').get(0).play(); //Optional, Play The video

});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb25p/

Comment: I tested it out and it makes the image/video "flash" to white but doesn't actually change it. Do you know what I can do so that the <li> item becomes the bigImg?

This is the page I'm working on http://theinfluence.co/traackr.html. When I use the html with the video it adds the video on top instead of replacing the larger img. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the video meant to replace the image? Video and Images are not directly able to be swapped. They are completely different elements. If this is the case it is a matter of hiding one and showing the other. From your page it is hard to tell what you want.

Comment: I want the video to be one more thumbnail in the list, that you can hover over. It should be a thumbnail of the video so that it's not different elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the video object again after changing the source(`src`) of video tag. Something like this:

```
$("#divVideo video")[0].load();
```

Also for changing source, you should be changing `src` of source tag that is inside video tag.

```
$('#divVideo video source').attr('src', videoFile);
```

**DOM:**

```
<div id="divVideo">
<video controls>
<source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Where should I include this? After the $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));? 

Just so that I understand a little more, why does the video object need to be reloaded each time?

Comment: First of all that is not the correct dom for video object. See the dom i have shared. and you need to right the src change and load on mouseover.

Comment: Yes, I've changed the DOM. I'm not sure how the js works yet. Does this work for the images as well?

Comment: ya. but you dont have to use load for images. they gets loaded on src change too